# undefined index 'value' in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, api

im using laravel 7 and trying to get datas from api use http.

**when i use dd('$datas'),i got this**

```
array:1 [▼"manajemen_sdm" => array:4 [▼ 0 => array:9 [▼ "id_karyawan" => "2" "nama" => "Koko Hendriko" "gender" => "Laki-Laki" "ttl" => "1998-04-07" "alamat" => "Kp.Palasari " "no_telp" => "821863141" "email" => "kokohendriko@gmail.com" "npwp" => "89678923652" "golongan" => "B" ] 1 => array:9 [▶] 2 => array:9 [▶] 3 => array:9 [▶] ] ]
```

**my controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $datas = Http::get('https://projectsoadenis.000webhostapp.com/api')->json();

    return view('sdm.index',compact('datas'));
}
```

**view**

```
 @foreach ($datas as $datasdm)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$no++}}</td>
                    <td>{{$datasdm['id_karyawan']}}</td>
                    <td>{{$datasdm['nama']}}</td>
                    <td>{{$datasdm['gender']}}</td>
                    <td>{{$datasdm['ttl']}}</td>
                    <td>{{$datasdm['alamat']}}</td>
                    <td>{{$datasdm['no_telp']}}</td>
                    <td>{{$datasdm['email']}}</td>
                    <td>{{$datasdm['npwp']}}</td>
                    <td>{{$datasdm['golongan']}}</td>
                </tr>  
            @endforeach
```

Comment: within foreach not using `manajemen_sdm` data..manajemen_sdm has to be loop ..also no check for undefined ..u can use $datasdm['golongan']?? '' after fixes to prevent undefined index error

Comment: im try $datasdm['manajemen_sdm]['id_karyawan'],but still not working

Comment: an you give me an example code?

Comment: `@foreach ($datas['manajemen_sdm'] as $datasdm) ....  cal inner loop data  $datasdm['id_karyawan'] .. @endforeach`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the data you are getting back from the API, your data is actually nested inside objects that live under a `manajemen_sdm` property.

Your loop should work correctly if you update it to loop over the `manajemen_sdm` key:

```
@foreach ($datas['manajemen_sdm'] as $datasdm)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$no++}}</td>
        <td>{{$datasdm['id_karyawan']}}</td>
        <td>{{$datasdm['nama']}}</td>
        <td>{{$datasdm['gender']}}</td>
        <td>{{$datasdm['ttl']}}</td>
        <td>{{$datasdm['alamat']}}</td>
        <td>{{$datasdm['no_telp']}}</td>
        <td>{{$datasdm['email']}}</td>
        <td>{{$datasdm['npwp']}}</td>
        <td>{{$datasdm['golongan']}}</td>
    </tr>  
@endforeach
```